# Camel org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException

Tags: java, apache-camel

we are using **camel direct component** in our project.

Application will work fine most of the time.
But sometimes services won't work because of following exception.
if we restart server again things will go normal.

we are not following any route startup order to start camel routes. All routes will load at deployment time only.

**we are using camel 2.16.1 version.**

Could any one suggest what causing this issue and why it is occurring often.

**Caused by: org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://framework-logger-service].**

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when "direct://framework-logger-service" route is not initialized in your application context.

but if it occurs sometimes then direct being a synchronous component it may not be available for accepting requests while processing other requests.

This behavior is possible when you send huge number of requests to direct component.

Comment: Yes, you can use the `block=true` option on the endpoints when sending, so they will wait until a consumer is ready (timeout is 30 sec). See more details at: http://camel.apache.org/direct

Comment: @ClausIbsen if we use "block=true" option on the endpoint does it impact  performance in production system?

Comment: No there is no performance overhead. This just ensures that sending to routes that are not yet ready will wait until its ready when Camel is starting up. Or you restart a route or something.

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach will be split your direct to two components to load balance

```
from(somesource).to(direct:total);

from(direct:total)
.multicast()
.parallelProcessing()
.to(direct:part1,direct:part2);
```